# ggplot axis custom order with duplicate labels

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
set.seed(357)
x <- data.frame(name = sample(letters, 10), val = runif(10), stringsAsFactors = F)
x[c(2,6),"name"] <- c("k","k")
ggplot(x, aes(x = name, y = val)) + theme_bw() + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

How can I plot the axis in the same order as x$name? (Yes, the k is duplicate, I want that to show up in the plot like this axis: c k g f o k s v t q)

In the past I used to do:

```
x$name <- factor(x$name, levels = x$name[order(x$val)], ordered = T)
```

which doesn't work any more thanks to:
http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/factors-with-non-unique-quot-duplicated-quot-levels-have-been-deprecated-since-2009-are-more-depreca-td4721481.html

This is no duplicate of: [ggplot: order of factors with duplicate levels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22340053/ggplot-order-of-factors-with-duplicate-levels)
His data structure is completely different.

Also, I have tried setting limits in x_scale_discrete. Doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this...

```
x$name2 <- 1:nrow(x)
ggplot(x, aes(x = factor(name2), y = val)) + theme_bw() + geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
             scale_x_discrete(labels=x$name)
```

Comment: i tried this with a time series data where the same date is repeated more than once in the x-axis, this solution simply stacks the repeating values into one. Doesn't show them separately somehow.

Comment: @samsamara It is hard to tell without seeing your data. It would probably be best for you to ask this as a separate question, with a reproducible example and a clear description of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: No worries. I posted a question and got the answer. It was just that I needed to use 'position_dodge()' in the geom object. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65316274/how-to-have-separate-columns-for-duplicate-x-axis-values-in-geom-col

Answer (score 0):

Actually, simply add the following setting `xlab(x$name)`

```
ggplot(x, aes(x = name, y = val)) + theme_bw() + geom_bar(stat = "identity") + xlab(x$name)
```

Comment: Sorry, not working. ggplot2 automatically thinks both k belong together and puts them in one bar.