# How to have separate columns for duplicate x-axis values in geom_col()?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar, geom-col

I have a dataframe as below (very simple structure) and I want to draw a column chart to show the amount for each date. The issue is that the `date` has duplicate entries (e.g., `2020-01-15`).

```
  # A tibble: 5 x 2
  date       amount
  <date>      <dbl>
1 2020-01-02  4000 
2 2020-01-06  2568.
3 2020-01-15  2615.
4 2020-01-15  2565 
5 2020-01-16  2640
```

When I try doing the following it somehow groups the similar dates together and draws a stacked column chart which is NOT what I want.

```
df %>%  
    ggplot(aes(x= factor(date), y=amount)) +
    geom_col()
    scale_x_discrete( labels = df$date ) #this creates discrete x-axis labels but the values are still stacked. So it just messes things up.
```

There's no issue if i'm using `geom_line()` but I want to see a bar for each date. Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Please [make this question reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) by including example data in a plain text format - for example the output from `dput(yourdata)`. We cannot copy/paste data from images.

Comment: @neilfws I have edited my question as per your comment. Thanks.

Comment: can someone tell me why this question has been negged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(date, amount)) +
  geom_col(position = position_dodge2()) + 
  scale_x_date(breaks = unique(df$date))
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: It was the positon_dodge2() then. Thanks  for the help: )